# Pronormality of Sylow subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need help on proving that every Sylow subgroup of a finite group is pronormal.

A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is said to be pronormal if for each $g\in G$, the subgroups $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$ are conjugate in $\langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle$

let $G$ be a finite group and let P be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. I know that for  any $g\in G$, $gPg^{-1}$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. I also know that all the Sylow $p$-subgroups of of $G$ are conjugate.

I need clarification on the subgroup $\langle P, gPg^{-1}\rangle$

Comment: Could you include a definition of pronormal?

Comment: Let $H = \langle P, gPg^{-1} \rangle$. Then $P$ and $gPg^{-1}$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $H$, so they are conjugate in $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation: $P^g = g^{-1}Pg$, and $Q=<P,P^x >$.

Since $Q$ is a subgroup of $G$, the highest power of $p$ dividing $|Q|$  is less or equal to the one dividing $|G|$ (call the latter $n$) and it is actually equal since $Q$ contains a subgroup of order $p^n$ ($P$), which means that $P$ and $P^g$ are also $p$-Sylow subgroups of $Q$.

Since $p$-Sylow subgroups are all conjugate, there exists some element $x$ in $Q$ such that $P^x = P^g$. Therefore $P$ is pronormal in $G$.